# Four people $(B,W,R,Y)$ are playing a game.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

$4$ people, designated Black, White, Red, and Yellow, are playing a game. Each of them has unlimited number of balls, all of that person’s designated color. They work together to build a line of balls. Each player can **either** add one colored ball **or** throw away the last ball in line and add two colored balls. The game begins with a single green ball.

> **Find $a_n$ (recursion) if the players plays in a fixed rotation**. Then find another $a_n$ that the players can play in any order, provided that no player ever makes two moves in a row.

I'm struggling finding the first $a_n$, anyone has any suggestions?

I thought about the situation if the turns are $B\to W\to R\to Y$. For $B$ we will have two options, and both of them will end with $2$ balls in the line, which means we can finish with $a_{n-2}$ possibilities. With White we will have $3$ balls or $1$ ball in line. With Red we will have $4$ balls or $2$ balls in line if it was $3$ balls after White played, and if we had one ball after White played, we will have $3$ balls or $2$ balls. And there will be $8$ options after Yellow plays. And then we sum all the possibilities into a huge, possibly wrong, equation.

Comment: May I suggest not saying "colored people"?  It might be misinterpreted.  Also, I don't think the rules are clear.  If player $X's$ moves are "add $1$" or "subtract $1$ and add $2$" then in all cases the length of the chain goes up by $1$.

Comment: @lulu I see. So it always grow by one. Which means, $a_n = a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-4} + a_{n-5}$ opinions?

Comment: You did not define $a_n$.  If it refers to the length then it is just $n$ (or $n+1$ depending on what you call the first move).  If it means the number of possible strings then $a_n=2^n$ (again depending on what you mean by $n$) as each possible path gives rise to two new ones on each turn.

Comment: @Ilan: I assume that $a_n$ is either the number of distinct lines that can result after $n$ moves or the number of possible lines of length $n$. Your comment about ‘$a_{n-2}$ possibilities’ makes me think that you mean the number of possible lines of length $n$, but it really isn’t clear; exactly what is $a_n$?

Comment: @Ilan: Also, I don’t see how you can possibly get $1$ ball in line after White’s first move in the last paragraph: no matter which option a player chooses, he *always* ends up increasing the length of the line by one ball.